# Как правильно хранить данные текущего пользователя в Angular?

Tags: angular2, asp.net-web-api

В общем, приложение является оберткой над WinApi с виндовой аутентификацией.

У меня встал вопрос:

Как правильно хранить данные пользователя, что бы потом на основании их отрисовывать те или иные компоненты?

Является ли верным решением сделать какой-нибудь `AuthorizationService`, а при заходе на сайт через этот сервис пользователь будет обращаться к WebAPI и получать свои роли, а потом его прокидывать во все компоненты? Это верный подход или в Angular принято по другом?

Под данными пользователя я подразумеваю его роли.

Comment: что вам мешает это сделать и почему вы считаете что angular чем-то ограничен в этом вопросе?

Comment: Да я спрашиваю, правильный ли данный подход в ангуляре или нет.